# Can't access ftp server

Tags: ftp

Before installing ubuntu I used windows.My internet provider has a ftp site.
In windows I just open a browser and visit the ftp site.But I can access the
ftp site in ubuntu.In firefox it says

Comment: Please update your post with the error message you get.

Comment: I get error 404 page not found. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

FTP should work in your web browser, you can also add FTP connections to Nautilus (the default file manager in Ubuntu) and Filezilla is also available in the Software Center (FileZilla in Ubuntu will be identical to FileZilla in windows).

Comment: how can i open ftp in browser. Tell me in detail.

Comment: You can access FTP in the web browser by putting the FTP URL into the address bar. Normally if you need a user name and password, your browser should be able to handle that, too. Generally speaking, opening FTP in the browser is `read-only`, although I'm sure there are browser add-ons/plugins available to do more than that with FTP connections.